# Get several id from pipe-separated string to concat data from another table

Tags: sqlite

I've got two tables, where one holds several id's as pipe-separated string and another that holds names for each id. I want to concat the names as one-liner string with \n between the names.

**Tables:**

**Id-table**

```
|   StringIds   |

'1|2|3|4|5|4|1'
```

**Name-table**

```
| StringId | String Name |

  1        'One'

  2        'Two'

  3        'Three'

  4        'Four'

  5        'Five'
```

**I've tried with following code without any success:**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(StringName || '\n')
FROM Names 
WHERE 
   StringId 
   IN
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(StringIds,'|',',')) 
      FROM Ids
```

) 
ORDER BY StringName ASC

Expected output: 'One'\n'Two'\n'Three'\n'Four'\n'Five'\n

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/aed32/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the sub query that you have used

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    group_concat(replace(StringIds,'|',',')) 
  FROM Ids
```

actually returns a string `'1,2,3,...'` not a number list `1,2,3,...` as expected.

The `WHERE StringId IN ((SELECT...))` wil not work with strings, it expects a list of elements and the string is ONE element.

So instead you will have to look at the string functions, and there you can use the INSTR(X,Y) function to find the StringId.

But here we must pay attention, because if i.E. we where searching for 
the number `3` then we would find it in:

```
1,2,3,4
```

but it would also find it in

```
1,2,30,4
```

So the trick is to wrap the separator around the query string 
and the string to search in. So if we would search for `',3,'` in `',1,2,3,4,'`
we would have a match, as expected, and if we search in `',1,2,30,4,'`, then we will not match, which is also as expected. So this is the reason we have these strange concats in our query :)

```
SELECT group_concat(StringName || '\n') as AllNames
FROM Names 
WHERE INSTR(
  (',' || (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      group_concat(replace(StringIds,'|',',')) 
    FROM Ids
  ) || ','),
  (',' || StringId || ',')
) > 0
ORDER BY StringName ASC;
```

Well now, if we think about it, and since we are searching in a string, 
we might as well use your oringinal string instead
of converting it in advance:

```
SELECT group_concat(StringName || '\n') as AllNames
FROM Names 
WHERE INSTR(
  ('|' || (
    SELECT StringIds FROM Ids LIMIT 1
  ) || '|'),
  ('|' || StringId || '|')
) > 0
ORDER BY StringName ASC;
```

And actually there are many more ways we could do this. Let me give you one last version using `LIKE` comparison instead of `INSTR` function:

```
SELECT group_concat(StringName || '\n') as AllNames
FROM Names 
WHERE
  ('|' || (
    SELECT StringIds FROM Ids LIMIT 1
  ) || '|')
  LIKE
  ('%|' || StringId || '|%')
ORDER BY StringName ASC;
```

Hope this link works, so you can [Fiddle around here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/aed32/43)

**UPDATE**

If you end up having more entries in your Ids table and you want to print out the unique names for each entry in the Ids table, then you have to turn around the query:

```
SELECT
( SELECT group_concat(StringName || '\n')
  FROM Names 
  WHERE
    ('|' || (
      StringIds
    ) || '|')
    LIKE
    ('%|' || StringId || '|%')
  ORDER BY StringName ASC
 ) as AllNames FROM Ids
```

Now here Ids is the outer table looped through and for each entry the sub query is performed, which returns the AllNames value.

Comment: Thanks.. Will the last option work even if it is several rows of stringname's refering to same stringid?

Comment: @Henrik don't worry, even if you have 15 times a three in your StringIds, it would match 15 times in theory, but you are selecting from Names, so it will check StringId for StringId and so no duplicates will be selected

Comment: @Henrik if this helped you, please mark the question as answered!

Comment: I mean if i add Another row that also have '6' in the stringid i want it to be included. But it wont :( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/29e5b/3

Comment: @Henrik that is because of the `LIMIT 1` in the `SELECT StringIds...` query. if you would change that to `LIMIT 1,1` then you would get the six as well. the query was just designed to fetch result for ONE stringIds value.

Comment: Okey, if i'll use LIMIT 1,1 instead and add Another row it will only pick the first 2 rows. If i remove the limitation it will only read the first row. I need the rows to be unlimited :(

Comment: @Henrik example updated, last query takes all entries from Ids table

Comment: thank for trying, this result returns distinct values of each row but i want distinct values from all rows combining.

Comment: @Henrik well no problem, the secret is `group_concat`, just use the first query from my answer, it will deliver exactly the result you expect, as you can [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d8594/1/0)